# in react component not see function in statical or classical way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i have write this function in this component 
but its not change anything look like not see the function 
import React from 'react'

```
export default React.createClass({
    var arrNum=[15,16,35,36,37,38,39,40];
      var check=function(imgURL){
      var newUrl="";
      var imgNum=imgURL.slice(45,47)
      imgNum=Number(imgNum)
        for(var i=0;i < arrNum.length; i++){
            if(imgNum === arrNum[i]){
              newUrl=imgURL;
              newUrl=newUrl.replace(imgNum,imgNum+"_en");
              return newUrl
            }
          }
              return imgURL
      }
  render() {

    return <div>
     <div className="main">
          <img className="img1" src=check({this.props.img1})/>
          <img className="img2" src=check({this.props.img2})/>
          <img className="img3" src=check({this.props.img3})/>
          <img className="img4" src=check({this.props.img4})/>

     </div> 
   </div>
  }
})
```

how i can make this function work in react ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the logic inside `render`, but before `return`

Example:

```
export default React.createClass({

  render() {
     var arrNum=[15,16,35,36,37,38,39,40];
      var check=function(imgURL){
      var newUrl="";
      var imgNum=imgURL.slice(45,47)
      imgNum=Number(imgNum)
        for(var i=0;i < arrNum.length; i++){
            if(imgNum === arrNum[i]){
              newUrl=imgURL;
              newUrl=newUrl.replace(imgNum,imgNum+"_en");
              return newUrl
            }
          }
              return imgURL
      }

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="main">
          <img className="img1" src=check({this.props.img1})/>
          <img className="img2" src=check({this.props.img2})/>
          <img className="img3" src=check({this.props.img3})/>
          <img className="img4" src=check({this.props.img4})/>

        </div> 
      </div>
    )  
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`ReactClass` signature is  :

```
 ReactClass({
  functionName1 : functionItself1, 
  functionName3 : functionItself2, 
//....
  render : functionRenderItself,   
});
```

So you can consider `check` function as the `function1` to have :

```
 ReactClass({
  check :/*...*/, 
  render : functionRenderItself,   
});
```

Then to access to `check` from `render` you have to precede it by `this.`

```
<img className="img1" src={this.check({this.props.img1)} />
```

#### Result :

```
const arrNum = [15, 16, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40];

export default React.createClass({
  check:  function(imgURL) {
  var newUrl = "";
  var imgNum = imgURL.slice(45, 47)
  imgNum = Number(imgNum)
  for (var i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++) {
    if (imgNum === arrNum[i]) {
      newUrl = imgURL;
      newUrl = newUrl.replace(imgNum, imgNum + "_en");
      return newUrl
    }
  }
  return imgURL
},
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
       <div className="main">
            <img className="img1" src={this.check(this.props.img1)} />
            <img className="img2" src={this.check(this.props.img2)}/>
            <img className="img3" src={this.check(this.props.img3)} />
            <img className="img4" src={this.check({this.props.img4)} />

       </div> 
     </div>
    );
  }
})
```

Did you believe that  your code can be refactored to be :

```
const arrNum = [15, 16, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40];

export default React.createClass({
  check: function(imgURL) {
    const imgNum = Number(imgURL.slice(45, 47));
    imgNum = arrNum.find((item) => item === imgNum);
    return (!imgNum) ? imgURL : imgURL.replace(imgNum, imgNum + "_en");
  },
  range: function(length) {
    return Array.from({length}, (v, k) => k + 1);
  },
  render: function() {
     return (
       <div>
        <div className="main">
         {
           this.range(4).map(i => <img className={"img"+ i} src={this.check(this.props["img"+i])} />)
         }
        </div>
       </div>
     );
  }
})
```

Comment: i did this 


import React from 'react'


const arrNum = [15, 16, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40];

export default React.createClass({
  check:  function(imgURL) {
  var newUrl = "";
  var imgNum = imgURL.slice(45, 47)
  imgNum = Number(imgNum)
  for (var i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++) {
    if (imgNum === arrNum[i]) {
      newUrl = imgURL;
      newUrl = newUrl.replace(imgNum, imgNum + "_en");
      return newUrl
    }
  }
  return imgURL
},
  render: function() {

Comment: return (
      <div>
     <div className="main">
          
          <img className="today_img" src={this.check(this.props.imagedayA}}/>
          <img className="night_img" src={this.check(this.props.imagenightA}}/>                    
          <img className="tomday_img" src={this.check(this.props.imagedayB)}/>
          <img className="tomnight_img" src={this.check(this.props.imagenightB)}/>
     
     </div> 
   </div>
    );
  }
})